# Jelastic built-in file browser did not show subfolders

Tags: jelastic

I've deployed application in http://app.jelasticloud.com/ .

Application has file structure:

```
- www
-- vendors
--- moaction
---- moaction
--- twig
---- twig
```

The problem is that folders `www/vendors/moaction/moaction and www/vendors/twig/twig` are not accessible via file browser.

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy the application? From zip/tar, FTP, git etc.? If FTP, did you modify chmod - the problem may be that the Jelastic dashboard doesn't have read permissions there due to chmod values.

Alternatively it could be caused by browser cache; did you try logout/login again?

What did your hosting provider's support say about the issue? They can see the details at the server level to verify any issue at that side...

Comment: The problem is when subfolder has the same name as his parent. If I change parent folder name, I can access subfolder.

Comment: I've contacted provider support (no answer at this moment), but for me it looks like upstream's (jelastic) issue.